# Zsh handling of substring changed?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I have over a thousand directories holding MP3 files and text.  I work on one directory each day, assisted by zsh scripts.  I mostly use zsh on command line and in scripts.  The paths are in the form `45_rom/007` which I pass to the scripts as a parameter.

17 Sep 2023, I decided to keep a history of which directory worked on each day.  To separate the two parts, I added

```
  BK=$1[1,6]
  CH=$1[8,10]
…
echo "${BK} ${CH}     $(basename $0)  $(date "+%a %Y %b %d %H:%M")" \
               >> $HOME/Bible/History
```

These lines have not changed since then, yet the history file contains

```
45_rom/007     EB  Tue 2024 Feb 13 10:18
45_rom 007[1,6] 45_rom 007[8,10]     EB  Tue 2024 Feb 13 13:14
```

Testing today shows that the script EB is still doing the latter format.  But the same syntax typed into an interactive shell behaves as expected.

As far as I know, the last global change was 3 Feb, before this started happening:

```
WGroleau@MBP ~ % ls -latd .??* | head
-rw-------    1 WGroleau  staff    548 Feb 15 08:38 .lesshst
drwx------+   2 WGroleau  staff     64 Feb 15 07:56 .Trash
drwxrwxr-x   92 WGroleau  staff   2944 Feb 15 07:50 .zsh_sessions
-rwxrwxr--    1 WGroleau  staff  58054 Feb 15 07:38 .zsh_history
-rwxrwxr--    1 WGroleau  staff    888 Feb 14 14:15 .wget-hsts
-rw-rw-r--    1 WGroleau  staff  28676 Feb 11 22:30 .DS_Store
-rwxrwxr--    1 WGroleau  staff    646 Feb  3 22:25 .zshrc      ←←
-rwxrwxr--    1 WGroleau  staff  17901 Feb  3 22:25 .viminfo
drwxrwxr-x    8 WGroleau  staff    256 Jan  3 08:56 .gnupg
-rwxrwxr--    1 WGroleau  staff  15601 Sep 11 08:37 .bash_history
```

And that change was to merely output `tail -4 $HOME/Bible/History` each time I open a Terminal window.

**What could have changed the behavior of `BK=$1[1,6]` in zsh acripts but not interactively?**

Comment: Tagging problem: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15159/tag-is-too-similar-to-itself

Comment: Do you know what version you updated from and to? Not sure what may have changed, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31120656) indicates you should to use `${1[1,6]}`.

Comment: IF zsh was updated, it was when the O.S. was updated 8 Feb or 15 Feb. The change in behavior happened 13 Feb.  So neither zsh nor the script changed when the behavior changed.

Comment: I will look into the syntax suggested by @ciclo.  Another way around it is to give up on splitting the path and just use $1   But I still wonder why the behavior changed.

Comment: @ciclo, the question for that answer quotes zsh documentation and saying my syntax should work—which it did until the thirteenth.  But I will certainly try the other.

Comment: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/zsh_a4.pdf: *... the numeric names of positional parameters
(Section 15.3 [Positional Parameters], page 83) are parsed specially, so for example ‘$2foo’
is equivalent to ‘${2}foo’. Therefore, to use subscript syntax to extract a substring from a
positional parameter, the expansion must be surrounded by braces; for example, ‘${2[3,5]}’
evaluates to the third through fifth characters of the second positional parameter, but ‘$2[3,5]’
is the entire second parameter concatenated with the filename generation pattern ‘[3,5]’."*